# How to define a vector based on a condition on its own cumulative sum?

Tags: r

I have a matrix and I would like to define a vector based on a condition on its own cumulative sum.

For example :

`data$m <- c(1, 0, 2, 1, 2)`

`data$n <- c(2, 1, 1, 2, 2)`

I would like to calculate data$x as :

`data$x <- data$m * data$n`

based on the condition that data$cumsum_x <- cumsum(data$x) is lower than a certain value, for example 5. If data$cumsum_x > 5, I should get data$x = 0

So I should get the following results for data$x :

`2 0 2 2 0`

Do you know how to do that?

I guess I should make a loop because data$x depends on the cumsum of n-1 ?

Comment: Something like `data$x[data$cumsum_x > 5] <-  0`

Comment: Or `ifelse(data$cumsum_x > 5, 0, data$x)`?

Comment: What other condition? You can do it all at once if you don't want temporary columns. `data$x = with(data, ifelse(cumsum(n * m) > 5, 0, n * m)`.

Comment: Or, if that `0` needs to reset the cumum for subsequent values, please edit your example to show that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think it answers my question.